# Safari style animations

Tags: mac, animations, gestures

Anybody know if it's possible to get mac book style animations on ubuntu? Specifically the back, forward, and exit tab animations.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome their is an extension that adds back and forward animations called [SwipeGesture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swipe-gesture/mgegfjnccpnkdppohmfgnjalkediapkc?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)